# Occupation number of a bosonic gas for high temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If we consider the average occupancy for a bose gas, we know:

$$\langle n \rangle_B=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)} -1}$$

I also know that for high temperatures this transforms itself to the occupancy for a classical Boltzmann gas:

$$\langle n \rangle_{MB}= e^{-\beta(\epsilon - \mu)}$$

I have a question here. We say the temperature increases, and for bosonic gases, the chemical potential goes to $-\infty$. Therefore in this expression: $\frac{\epsilon -\mu}{KT}$, both the temperature and the chemical potential increase.So why do we make the assumption that the chemical potential increases so much more then the temperature, hence why we get the Boltzmann expression in the end. Because we assumed that $e^{\beta(\epsilon - \mu)}>>1$

Comment: $e^{-\beta\mu}\gg 1$ is what it really means to have classical limit. If you fix the density and keep increasing $T$, the ratio $-\mu/T$ will increase as well and no assumption is needed.

Comment: but doesn't $\mu$ also tends to go to $-\infty$ while $T\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: See Chapter 3.5.2. of https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/statphys.pdf

Comment: Well the question is how $\mu/T$ behaves. Even both $\mu$ and $T$ both diverge, their ratio could have different limits.